# sql query with foreign constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Following the textbook "SQL in a Nutshell" It asks for the query

> For the employees with an email address display their age and gender.

On the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(
   PID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(PID),
   CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_FK FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES PERSONS (PID)
);

CREATE TABLE PERSONS(
 PID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 GENDER CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (GENDER IN ('M','F')),
 AGE SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK (AGE BETWEEN 0 AND 120),
 BIRTHDATE DATE NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(PID)
);

CREATE TABLE HASE(
 PID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 EADDR VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(PID,EADDR),
 CONSTRAINT HASE_FK FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES PERSONS (PID)
);
```

I'm very new to SQL queries so my attempt was:

```
SELECT GENDER, AGE
FROM PERSONS AND EMPLOYEES
WHERE EXISTS HASE.EADDR
;
```

But I dont think im getting the relation right with the foreign key. I realize this is very basic, but I think once I see the way the query is made it will help me with the others.

Comment: Not related to your question, but MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS to get your results

```
SELECT Gender, Age
FROM Persons
  JOIN Employees ON Persons.PID = Employees.PID
WHERE Exists (SELECT PID
              FROM Hase
              WHERE Persons.PID = Hase.PID)
```

You can also use an IN, but the EXISTS query will be faster

```
SELECT Gender, Age
FROM Persons
  JOIN Employees ON Persons.PID = Employees.PID
WHERE Persons.PID IN  (SELECT PID
                       FROM Hase)
```

Comment: +1, because this will return the expected results if the employee has *more than one* e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  persons.NAME,
  persons.GENDER,
  persons.AGE
FROM
  persons INNER JOIN employees
  ON persons.PID = employees.PID
  INNER JOIN hase
  ON persons.PID = hase.PID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bf4f/3).

Comment: Note that this query will require extra overhead because of the use of DISTINCT and joining on an additional table.

Comment: @MattBusche joins should not be a problem (you could also skip both joins, and use two IN clauses and an AND). But it is true that the DISTINCT might be slower.